# Set T for all generic methods on non generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Let's assume I have a class like

```
public class DataService
{
   public IList<T> All<T>() { ... }
   public T Get<T>(int id) { ... }
   ...
}
```

I could use it in various ways...

```
var dataService = new DataService();
var customers = dataService.All<Customer>();
var order = dataService.Get<Order>(1);
```

... but if I had a bunch of operations with the same T, this would become cumbersome. Then it would be nice to have something like this:

```
dataService.TypeIs<Order>();
var order2 = dataService.Get(2);
var order2 = dataService.Get(3);
var allOrders = dataService.All();
```

How would a `TypeIs<T>()` method look like? I think it had to somehow convert `DataService` to `DataService<T>` and set T... Or is this utterly impossible?

Comment: just out of curiosity: why don't you make the class generic?

Comment: For example, if I had to access orders and customers in the same place, then I'd have to instantiate `DataService<Order>`and `DataService<Customer>` wheras with the non generic class I cann just instantiate it and then use the generic methods. This doesn't seem like a big difference with just these two entities, but maybe there are some more like products, orderitems etc.

Comment: I mean, this is certainly not a thing that could be solved with just the generic version of the class. I just got curious, if something like this would be possible :-)

Comment: So basically you want to pour some syntactic sugar on your code? I don't think this is possible - it would be nice if c# could infer `T` from the variable you are assigning to (you'd have to change `var` to the actual type), but for some reason I don't think it can

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to create a generic repository. I recommend reading the following: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/

Comment: Not exactly. I know the article and have used generic repositories. What I try to acomplish is to avoid things like `public Index(IRepository<Order> ordersRepo, IRepository<Customer> custsRepo, IRepository<...> ...)` in favour of `public Index(IRespository repo)` but at the same time be prepared for cases where I only need the generic repository for one type. I basically want to kill two birds with one stone, where it's possibly not really worth the effort :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using a clever proxy:

```
public class DataService
{
   public IList<T> All<T>() { ... }
   public T Get<T>(int id) { ... }
   ...
}

public class DataServiceProxy<T>
{
    public DataServiceProxy(DataService ds)
    {
      this.ds = ds;
    }

    public IList<T> All() 
    { 
      return this.ds.All<T>();
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
      return this.ds.Get<T>(id);
    }
}
```

The equivalent of your `dataService.TypeIs<Order>();` is `var dataServiceProxy = new DataServiceProxy<Order>(dataService)`.

Comment: This was my first thought too. I'd really like to avoid the duplication of the whole class though. But maybe this is the closest I can get.

Comment: Well, there is a possibility using reflection, but still, not to repeat the desired type in each call some dynamically compiled code would have to be introduced.

Comment: Yes but doing reflexion over Generics become difficult to follow code overtime. But if the project is quite small then it's probably the best solution if you really don't want to use Proxy/Wrapper class.

Comment: This is not a duplication of the entire class. Only of the interface. The internals are not duplicated.

Comment: You're right. However If I add a new method to `DataService` I have to add it to `DataServiceProxy` as well.

Comment: Anyway, since this seems the closest to what I imagine, I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks, @BartoszKP.